# Assign Individual Visual into Subplots with Loop in Python

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
    for p in range(1,10):
        for i in df2.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(2,5,p)
            ax= plt.pie(df2[i].value_counts(),labels=df2[i].unique())
```

When I use this. It assigns the same subplots instead of creating an individual subplot based on the column's value. I am assuming there is an issue with the double loop.

Comment: What library are you using, matplotlib? Please [edit] to add the tag and the import statement in the code.

Comment: You need to change this line `ax= plt.pie(df2[i].value_counts(),labels=df2[i].unique())` to `ax.pie(df2[i].value_counts(),labels=df2[i].unique())`. Because you have to use the new axes returned by the function above that `add_subplot`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to amend the code as you specified.  However, getting the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately solved the problem. I took the information that you guys provided and it lead me down the right path. I need to use iloc to isolate the columns

```
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
for i in range(1,9):
    fig.add_subplot(2,5,i)
    plt.pie(df2.iloc[:,i].value_counts(),labels=df2.iloc[:,i].unique(),autopct='%.2f%%',textprops={'color':"black"})
    plt.title(df2.columns[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [
    [15, 30, 45, 10],
    [25, 10, 30, 35],
    [45, 30, 15, 10],
    [15, 30, 25, 30],
    [15, 50, 25, 10],
    [15, 30, 45, 10],
    [15, 30, 45, 10],
    [25, 20, 45, 10],
    [15, 20, 55, 10],
    [15, 20, 55, 10],
    [15, 20, 45, 20]
]

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(1, 11):
    ax = figure.add_subplot(2, 5, i)
    ax.pie(sizes[i], labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

And it gave me the following output.

[image]

Comment: This is good. However, this does not loop through the columns in the previous code.